# getting exception on below singleton in java

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton

I have given this  below problem

Complete the Singleton class in your editor which contains the following components:

```
A private Singleton non parameterized constructor.
A public String instance variable named .
Write a static method named getSingleInstance that returns the single instance of the Singleton class.
```

Once submitted, our hidden Solution class will check your code by taking a String as input and then using your Singleton class to print a line.

Input Format

```
You will not be handling any input in this challenge.
```

Output Format

```
You will not be producing any output in this challenge.
```

Sample Input

```
hello world
```

Sample Output

```
Hello I am a singleton! Let me say hello world to you
```

for this challenge I have designed the below class

```
class Singleton  implements Cloneable,Serializable {

public static volatile Singleton str = null; 

   private  Singleton ()
   {

       if (str!=null)
       {
           throw new IllegalStateException("object already instaniated");
       }
   }



   public static Singleton getSingleInstance()
   {
       if (str==null)
           synchronized (Singleton.class)
           {
               if (str==null)
               {
                   str= new Singleton(); 
               }

        }
       return str ;
   }}
```

but now i am getting this below exception please advise how to overcome from this

```
Main.java:66: error: incompatible types
    s1.str=str;
           ^
  required: Singleton
  found:    String
Main.java:67: error: incompatible types
    s2.str=str;
           ^
  required: Singleton
  found:    String
2 errors
```

folks please advise

Comment: It’s an aside, it appears to me that implementing `Cloneable` and `Serializable` goes against the idea of a singletin?

Comment: It's not smart to have a singleton that is clonable. By definition cloning duplicates the cloned object, and then it's not a singleton. Nothing wrong with `Serializable` except that to get it right you really need to know what you're doing. Unless you implement the singleton antipattern correctly, in which case you have a correct implementation of serializability for free. Follow the advice of Joshua Bloch's _Effective Java_ in the real world - implement a singleton with a single-constant `enum`.

Comment: Look up "double-checked locking", and why you should never use it even if you got it right.  Don't use lazy initialization in a singleton; Java already initializes the type lazily so you're totally wasting effort making your code too complicated adding lazier initialization.

Answer (score 0):

Your `str` in your singleton class is a singleton itself. The error shows you are assigning a string to a singleton, which is obviously not possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot , please advise then how to overcome from this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in your main class?

Comment: Once submitted, our hidden Solution class will check your code by taking a String as input and then using your Singleton class to print a line.

Comment: You can set a string to an *attribute* of your singleton. Assigning a `String` to a different type just doesn't work in a strongly-typed language. Assigning a new value to a singleton itself destroys the singleton property.